# State lost value in bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am using custom fields in react bootstrap table.

```
 {
  dataField: "hours",
  text: "# of Hours",
  sort: true,
  footer: "# of Hours",
  headerStyle: (colum, colIndex) => {
    return { width: "10%" };
  },
  formatter: (cellContent, row) => {
    return (
      <div className="form-row">
        <AvForm>
          <Controls.Input
            name="hours"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Hours"
            value={rosterData.hours}
            handleChange={handleChange}
          />
        </AvForm>
      </div>
    );
  },
},
```

**My handle change Function**

```
    const [rosterData, setRosterData] = useState({
    S_time: "21:00",
    hours: "",
  });



 const handleChange = (evt) => {
    const value = evt.target.value;
    setRosterData({ ...rosterData, [evt.target.name]: value });
  };
```

When I enter the value in field, state set that value, but when I click on save button for using that value, state becomes empty.

**Button for saving data**

```
{
  dataField: "action",
  text: "Action",
  footer: "Action",
  isDummyField: true,
  formatter: (cellContent, row) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <AiFillSave
          style={{ color: "#0190d5", cursor: "pointer" }}
          onClick={() => submitRoster(row.id)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  },
},
```

**function for save button**

```
const submitRoster = (id) => {
const data = {
  id: id,
  S_time: rosterData.S_time,
  hours: rosterData.hours,
};
console.log("onclick Data=", data);
};
```

[image: console while changing one field]

[image: console while changing other value]

[image: console when click on save button]

Comment: Have you tried with checking on change with useEffect ?

Comment: Where do you get this `hours: rosterData.hours`?

Comment: NO i didn't tried it yet

Answer (score 0):

react-bootstrap-table does not detect state changes. Pass your state variables to formatExtraData property, and use it from 4th parameter of your formatter function as shown in [docs](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Work%20on%20Columns&selectedStory=Dummy%20Column&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel).

```
{
  dataField: "hours",
  text: "# of Hours",
  sort: true,
  footer: "# of Hours",
  headerStyle: (colum, colIndex) => {
    return { width: "10%" };
  },
  formatExtraData: {rosterData, setRosterData},
  formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex, extraData) => {
    return (
      <div className="form-row">
        <AvForm>
          <Controls.Input
            name="hours"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Hours"
            value={rosterData.hours}
            handleChange={e => handleChange(e, extraData)}
          />
        </AvForm>
      </div>
    );
  },
}
```